# External mouse/keyboard @ LG display no longer recognized over thunderbolt

Tags: macos, usb, thunderbolt, high-sierra, driver

I have MacBook Pro Mid 2015 running macOS 10.13.1, and I used to attach an LG 34UC98-W display via a Thunderbolt port on the MBP, with external mouse and keyboard plugged into the USB ports of the display.

Since the Security Update 2017-001<sup>1</sup> the external mouse and keyboard are no longer recognized (the display still is, and if I plug the mouse into the USB port of the Macbook, it also works).

When I have the Thunderbolt cable plugged in, the console shows error messages like

```
default 13:27:35.937878 +0100   kernel  000930.777752 AppleUSB30XHCIPort@00200000: AppleUSBHostPort::forcePowerGated: kPowerStateSleep completed with 0xe00002d6 after 1001ms
default 13:27:36.612068 +0100   kernel  000931.451950 AppleUSBXHCIPCI@00000000: AppleUSBHostController::hardwareExceptionThreadCallGated: 0x00000040
default 13:27:37.153555 +0100   kernel  000931.993437 AppleUSBXHCIPCI@00000000: AppleUSBHostController::setPowerStateGated: going to state 1 returned 0xe00002e9
default 13:27:37.153597 +0100   kernel  000931.993487 AppleUSBXHCIPCI@00000000: AppleUSBHostController::hardwareExceptionThreadCallGated: attempting recovery
default 13:27:37.153610 +0100   kernel  000931.993499 AppleUSBXHCIPCI@00000000: AppleUSBHostController::hardwareExceptionThreadCallGated: 0x00000004
default 13:27:37.153629 +0100   kernel  000931.993519 AppleUSBXHCIPCI@00000000: AppleUSBHostController::hardwareExceptionThreadCallGated: attempting recovery
default 13:27:37.153739 +0100   kernel  000931.993619 AppleUSBXHCIPCI@00000000: AppleUSBXHCI::raiseOnePowerStateTo: host controller was not halted, USBStatus 0x00000018
default 13:27:38.154534 +0100   kernel  000932.994402 AppleUSB30XHCIPort@00100000: AppleUSBHostPort::forcePowerGated: kPowerStateSleep completed with 0xe00002d6 after 1001ms
default 13:27:38.730765 +0100   kernel  000933.570659 AppleUSB30XHCIPort@00200000: AppleUSBHostPort::forcePowerGated: kPowerStateSleep completed with 0xe00002d6 after 1039ms
default 13:27:38.730788 +0100   kernel  000933.570685 AppleUSBXHCIPCI@00000000: AppleUSBHostController::hardwareExceptionThreadCallGated: 0x00000080
default 13:27:38.881941 +0100   kernel  000933.721844 AppleUSBXHCIPCI@00000000: AppleUSBHostController::setPowerStateGated: going to state 1 returned 0xe00002e9
default 13:27:38.881969 +0100   kernel  000933.721873 AppleUSBXHCIPCI@00000000: AppleUSBHostController::hardwareExceptionThreadCallGated: 0x00000004
default 13:27:38.881977 +0100   kernel  000933.721884 AppleUSBXHCIPCI@00000000: AppleUSBHostController::forcePowerGated: waiting for previous forcePower completed with 0xe00002d8
```

Does anyone experience similar problems or can suggest a solution?

<sup>1</sup> The symptoms certainly seemed to start with the update, but as of now I can't prove it is actually the cause.

Comment: Update to 10.13.2 did not solve the problem. Contacted Apple Support, tried the usual suspects (resetting SMC, NVRAM etc.) but other than that they are unable/unwilling to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IT crowd to the rescue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8)...

It was not the macbook (tried everything: updating MacOS, resetting SMC, NVRAM, updating drivers, safe mode etc.). Simply disconnecting and reconnecting the display from the power solved the problem.

My only excuse is that the monitor was in standby many times during these trials, so I kind of thought it was turning off and on again. That wasn't enough, though.